# PHP if clause basic question

Tags: php, if-statement

a simple question

what is the differences between this:

```
if($posted_quantity <= $current_quantity) {
    if($posted_quantity >= $min_allowed_quantity && $posted_quantity <= $max_allowed_quantity){
        //do something
    }
}
```

and this:

```
if($posted_quantity <= $current_quantity && ($posted_quantity >= $min_allowed_quantity && $posted_quantity <= $max_allowed_quantity)){
    //do something
}
```

if it is possible, what is the differences between those two, which one is better to use, thanks much

**EDIT**:i am currently doing the testings and i don't seem to find any problem using both approach, and i don't have any elses, i simply want to do something once the whole conditions is fulfilled (to limit the user's quantity), i was just curious on which one is the better approach, which one is faster, readable, things like that

Comment: You don't have PHP near you to just try it? I case you really have not, you can test such simple things yourself with http://codepad.org/

Comment: it seems working on my current testings, i was just curious

Comment: @Felix Kling - i think **littlechad** came here to ask for suggestion and our/your advice! And question isnt What is this!?! He knows what is that and where to use it!

Comment: @littlechad: Then you should clarify that. If I read your question as it is now, it seems to me you are too lazy to run the code yourself... sorry for that but I can't help it.

Comment: @Felix Kling - thats not true because he did try it probably but read last line of his question... **what is the differences between those two, which one is better to use, thanks much**

Comment: ok @felix kling, i'll clarify my question, sorry for the misunderstanding

Comment: @FeRtoll: One part of the question is *is it possible to change this* and this is something which can be found out easily. Quite a few people are asking questions like this so that is why some of us might be a bit sensitive about this. Normally it shows that the OP put no effort so far into solving his problem/question. Only from his comment was clear that he tried it before, not from the question. And I'm not saying anything against the last line. It is perfectly fine (although I think the question was here before but I cannot find it...).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I you don't have any `else` or `elseif` clauses in there, it is exactly the same. Though I assume that your original condition was already wrong:

```
$posted_quantity <= $min_allowed_quantity && $posted_quantity >= $max_allowed_quantity
```

This is true if `$posted_quanitiy` is **outside** the the min..max range.

Answer (score 1):

It is indeed possible.

Functionally, they're equivalent, so the difference lies in readability, so go with whichever one you find the most easy to understand.

Personally I'd do something along the lines of

```
if ($posted_quantity <= $current_quantity &&
    $posted_quantity <= $min_allowed_quantity &&
    $posted_quantity >= $max_allowed_quantity) {
    //do something
}
```

in order to make it more readable.

Answer (score 1):

Both Style of if Conditions are valid it doesn't seem any difference better to use it in a single condition statement

Hope it Helps!!

Answer (score 0):

It's the same. The advantages of the first is being able to set an else clause for the second if, and readability.

Answer (score 0):

They do the same thing, in the same manner. In both cases if the first condition returns false the second one is not evaluated.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have any 'else' clause, your first if is useless.
Imo, the second is maybe a bit faster, since php doesn't have to parse 2 'if'. But I'm not sure.

Answer (score 0):

The first allows you to have seperate else clauses for each evaluated statement. You may wish to have different things happen if the first staement is false than if the second is false.

Answer (score 0):

Both are the same.
i think so Its your programming skill which one use depend on you(batter feeling for you and other easily understanding this code)

Answer (score 0):

ofc. anything is possible! ;)

```
if($posted_quantity <= $current_quantity && ($posted_quantity <= $min_allowed_quantity && $posted_quantity >= $max_allowed_quantity)){
  //do something
}
```

Its same if you always need to check for all of that!
But if you need to check like this:

```
if($posted_quantity <= $current_quantity){
  if($posted_quantity <= $min_allowed_quantity){
        //do something
  }
  elseif($posted_quantity >= $max_allowed_quantity){
        //do something else
  }
}
```

then it would go separated! :)